# MySQL Group by Query but with one query i need to convert Currency Rate & merge Result

Tags: sql, group-by

I have Table with Field

```
id | Customer | Currency Type | Sales Amt | Date
=====================================================
1  | ClientA  | Dollar        | 100$      | Timestamp
2  | ClientB  | Rupees        | 1500Rs    | Timestamp
```

I am trying query like `"Select Currency Type, Sum(Sales Amt) from Table where Date between start and End group by Currency Type"`

But i want to first calculate All Rupees amt first and then merge them with Dollar type. 
`Sum(Sales Amt)*45(Conversion rate) where currency='rupees"`

So in Result ill get only one Currency Type that is Dollar Amt so i can display reports on that basis.

Can it be possible? pls any one help me making this kind query or any otherway out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a searched `CASE` statement to determine for each record if you need to convert it to dollars or not.

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE [Currency Type]
              WHEN 'Rupees' THEN [Sales Amt] * 45
              WHEN 'Dollar' THEN [Sales Amt]
              WHEN 'Other'  THEN [Sales Amt] * ???
              ELSE [Sales Amt]
            END)
FROM    Table
WHERE   Date BETWEEN Start and End
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table CurrencyConvertTable
with following table structure and data

```
| CurrencyType | CurrencyConvertRate |
======================================
| Dollar        | 1                  | 
| Rupees        | 45                 |
```

Noq query like this..

```
Select CurrencyType
,Sum(SalesAmt*CurrencyConvertRate) 
from MainTable mt
JOIN CurrencyConvertTable ct
  ON mt.CurrencyType = ct.CurrencyType
where Date between start and End 
group by CurrencyType
```

Best way to handle more currency types..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an own table for the currency conversion factors.

```
conversion_id     source   target   factor
1                 Rupees   Dollar   45.0
2                 Dollar   Dollar   1.0
```

Now you can join the currency conversion table and calculate the sum dynamically without the use of a `CASE WHEN END` construct.
It would be better if you also design a currency table and use only currency ids.